# Set of vertices intersecting all faces of a planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Does anyone know if the following problem exists in the literature: Given a planar graph, find a minimum set of vertices intersecting all of its faces.

Answer (score 2):

Such a set is called a *face hitting set* of the planar graph. (Note that in general, this depends not only on the graph itself, but also on the embedding you choose.) This terminology does not come out of nowhere: a "hitting set" for any other kind of object is a set that intersects every instance of that object.

In particular, a cycle hitting set is also called a *feedback vertex set*, which intersects every cycle of a graph. If the graph is planar, then any feedback vertex set is of course a face hitting set, since all faces are cycles. I am given to understand that the paper [Connected feedback vertex set in planar graphs](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-642-11409-0_13) by A. Grigoriev and R. Sitters proves a half-converse: the size of the smallest feedback vertex set is at most twice the size of the smallest face hitting set. (But I can't check, since I don't have access to the paper from home.)

For some reason, lots of people are interested in finding connected face hitting sets. See for instance [Connecting face hitting sets in planar graphs](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ipl.2010.10.008) by Pascal Schweitzer and Patrick Schweitzer. This paper is where I got my citation for the at-most-twice-the-size fact above. It also proves a different interesting result: in a connected planar graph with minimum degree $3$, any face hitting set of size $n$ is contained in a connected face hitting set of size $5n-6$. (A factor of $5$ is the price you pay for connectivity.)

Why minimum degree $3$, by the way? Because if degree-$2$ vertices are allowed, you could subdivide each edge a billion times, inflating the size of a connected face hitting set tremendously while not affecting the general problem at all. But that's maybe more detail than you wanted to know.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is the parameter I was looking. Although I was looking for an upper bound for this parameter in terms of the size of a feedback vertex set, the references you gave seem a good starting point.